# Gray bar at top of screen

Tags: gnome, linux-mint

Running Linux Mint and GNOME, a dark grey bar just appeared at the top of my screen. When I maximize applications, they only go to the top of the visible window. However, applications can be manually dragged into the dead zone. The cursor is visible if hovered over the bar.

What information would be helpful? I have tried rebooting, it did not fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a [GNOME Panel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Panel). Right-click for options, including removal.